# How to apply slicing to a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I am trying to replace the following code:

```py
DfInt['Closest Service'] = DfInt[
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
     21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39,
     40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58,
     59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77,
     78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96,
     97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111,
     112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126,
     127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141,
     142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156,
     157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171,
     172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186,
     187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201,
     202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216,
     217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223]
].idxmin(axis=1)
```

by something like

```py
DfInt['Closest Service'] = DfInt[[0:224]].idxmin(axis=1)
```

But this is not working... Anyone an idea?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "But this is not working" - **what should the result be**?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel they're looking to replace the first code block with something more succinct. They've tried the second code block (and this does not produce the same output). I think it's reasonably clear that they're looking for the second code block to do what the first code block is doing.

Comment: @HenryEcker I just need more caffeine then. At any rate, the linked duplicate surely covers it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need select by labels use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), `:` is for select all rows:

```
DfInt['Closest Service'] = DfInt.loc[:, :223].idxmin(axis=1)
```

If select by positions - first 223 columns use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) by `224`:

```
DfInt['Closest Service'] = DfInt.iloc[:, :224].idxmin(axis=1)
```

Comment: DfInt['Closest Service (testkm)']=DfInt.loc[:,0:223:1].idxmin(axis=1)

Thank you Jezrael !  

All is working fine now using the line above.